# How do I run a Knex migration against a remote database?

Tags: knex.js

I have a remote database which I want to run Knex migrations against.

I see that there is a --connection flag in the Knex CLI documentation, but when I try

```
knex migrate:latest --connection [[my connection string]
```

I get

```
error: unknown option `--connection'
```

Comment: Does `knex --connection <connection_string> migrate:latest` work?

Comment: No, same error.

Comment: is this helpful at all <https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3305>?

Comment: I don't really understand the practical ramifications. OK, so in a bunch of scenarios the connection flag is ignored. But in my case, it just throws an error that it knows of no such flag.

Comment: which knex version are you using?

Comment: Knex version 0.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-CLI

you should have `knexfile.js` in your project folder.
File should contain some like this:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host : '127.0.0.1', // should be remote host
      user : 'your_database_user',
      password : 'your_database_password',
      database : 'myapp_test'
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can run migrations

By `npx knex migrate:latest`

Comment: Thanks-I have a valid knexfile. The issue is that I want to be able to target an environment when I migrate. Meaning, do a migration to local OR a migration to staging OR a migration to production.

Comment: module.export = { production: {}, development: {}}
And run node with env NODE_ENV=production